# Why is the Actual RAM Size Less Than It States?

Tags: linux, memory

According to the `/proc/meminfo` on my machine, I have 16366448 KiB of memory, which is approximately 15.6 GiB. But my two RAM sticks should have 16 GiB in total. Why so?

Comment: Do you perhaps have onboard/integrated graphics?

Comment: @DanielB no, I don't.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a GB vs. GiB mix up otherwise you'd have 14.88GiB of RAM (but I think it's often sold by GiB anyway)

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84695/proc-meminfo-memtotal#84766

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some RAM at different measure stages can be taken by:

1. CPU graphics card
2. text mode of terminal (legacy from MS-DOS)
3. BIOS/UEFI
4. operating system (both Windows and Linux) - kernel and other
5. dedicated graphic card (not in CPU)
6. other firmware depending on hardware

And that's why you can't see whole memory even if it is there.

About RAM you can be sure that it is there, I mean if you have 16 GiB of RAM, you strictly have 16*1024^3 = 17179869184 bytes.